# Can't save CNN model using tensorflow without training it again

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to save a Sequential CNN model. I've found that I can save it using `model.save()` but after I try to load it back using `keras.models.load_model()` it starts training itself again.

How can I save my model so I don't need to train it again?

Also while training I've got the following warning a couple of times, which says:

```
/15 [=>............................] - ETA: 39s - loss: 0.6936 - accuracy: 0.50782022-10-11 
17:31:06.794142: W tensorflow/tsl/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:82] 
Allocation of 358875136 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
```

Might this be a cause?

Here is code for this model:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle
PATH = 'cats_and_dogs\cats_and_dogs'

train_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'train')
validation_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'validation')
test_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'test')



# Variables for pre-processing and training.
batch_size = 128
epochs =1
IMG_HEIGHT = 150
IMG_WIDTH = 150


train_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
validation_image_generator =ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_data_gen = train_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                     directory=train_dir,
                                                     target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                     class_mode='binary')

val_data_gen = validation_image_generator.flow_from_directory(validation_dir, target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),  class_mode='categorical',batch_size=batch_size)
test_data_gen = test_image_generator.flow_from_directory(test_dir, target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH), classes ='.',class_mode='categorical',  batch_size=batch_size, shuffle = False)
#I,ve found that you can use classes = ".", to get test data labels (labels when there are no subdirectories ))
from tensorflow.python.framework.func_graph import flatten


model = tf.keras.Sequential()   
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3) , input_shape = (150,150,3)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3),activation = 'relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3),activation = 'relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_data_gen,
            epochs=epochs, 
            batch_size = batch_size,
            validation_data=val_data_gen,
            steps_per_epoch =2000//batch_size, 
            validation_steps=800//batch_size)



model.save('CatDog.h5')
```

And code of another file which i try to upload model to:

````
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas
import tkinter
import os
from CNNmodel import IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator #type: ignore
from tensorflow import keras
model = keras.models.load_model('CatDog.h5')```
````

Comment: NN training is quite simple conceptually: offer input, calculate output, compare with ground truth, calculate difference, update weights based on the difference. For inference, just stop after step 2, which means you don't provide a ground truth.

Comment: I am not following; the answer to the question "*How can I save my model?*" is to use `model.save()`, as you have already done here. If there is a problem after *loading* the model, please show that part of the code - the one you show here is actually irrelevant to your question.

Comment: I.m sorry i started to write questions here recently, I fixed the title of this post and i,ve added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It starts training again because you are probably calling `model.fit(...)` again.

This is sufficient to load back a model:

```
from tensorflow import keras
model = keras.models.load_model('path/to/location')
```

If you want to obtain predictions then you will have something like this, no need to train again:

```
prediction = model(test_data, training=False)
```

Comment: If you want a more precise answer please provide the code you have so far.

Comment: Hey thanks for answer but i only use fit once ( i dont use it again after loading) I edited my post with this code

Comment: @Patryk I am afraid you have not updated your code to show what the alleged error is, i.e. where you *load* the model and what happens afterwards; you only show how you have trained and saved the model, which is actually irrelevant to what you are actually asking here.

Comment: Oh yea you are right! Sorry

Comment: I added it, although i really don,t do anything other than using keras.model.load.model

Comment: Great, no problem

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: actually i fixed it thanks for help, In my second file i had imported some variables from model creation file,

`from CNNmodel import IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH`

And i guess model.fit got called somehow again